# how we can convert codeigniter code to laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5.1

### view code

how we can convert this code to laravel

```
<div class="property-grid">
          <ul class="grid-holder col-3">
            <?php foreach ($r as $row) : ?>
              <li class="grid-item type-rent">
                <div class="property-block"> <a href="<?=base_url()?>controller/buy_and_sell/<?= $row->sub_id; ?>" class="property-featured-image"> <img src="<?=base_url()?>real/images/background-images/sub-category-images/<?= $row->sub_cat_images;?>" alt=""> <span class="images-count"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> 2</span></a>
                  <div class="property-info">
                    <h4><a href="<?=base_url()?>controller/buy_and_sell/<?= $row->sub_id; ?>"><?= substr($row->sub_cat_name, 0, 24);?></a></h4>
                    <span class="location">NYC</span>
                    <div class="price"><strong>Records</strong>
                      <span>
                        <?php 
                        $data = $this->model->get_product_count($row->sub_id);
                          //echo array_shift($data);
                        echo $data['count'];
                        ?>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

### model code

```
function get_product_count($id){
    $query = $this->db->query("select COUNT(sub_id) AS count FROM products WHERE products.sub_id = $id");
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

this code convert to laravel
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

### this code convert

```
<span>
                        <?php 
                        $data = $this->model->get_product_count($row->sub_id);
                          //echo array_shift($data);
                        echo $data['count'];
                        ?>
                      </span>
```

Comment: <?php 
                        $data = $this->model->get_product_count($row->sub_id);
                          //echo array_shift($data);
                        echo $data['count'];
                        ?>

Comment: only convert this code to laravel

Comment: Please edit your question to include these comments/additions, instead of listing them separately.

Comment: By reading and understanding the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

To convert this CI code to laravel is quite simple. Just you should be aware of basic knowledge of laravel [MODEL(Eloquent ORM)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) concept and [routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing).

You have to make model first and just a simple query to get the product count or you can use query builder directly instead of using model.

Using model, you can do something like this:

```
Product::where('sub_id',$id)->count();
```

here `Product` is model.

If you want to use query builder, the equivalent query will be:

```
DB::table('products')->where('sub_id',$id)->count();
```

Here `products` is database table.

Another thing you have to know is to write and use routes to point the specific function in the controller with or with out parameter. Your code is not that clear in view, so I will give you a example:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

If this is your controller, then you can write route in the routes.php file to point to that index function as:

```
Route::get('/index','ProductController@index');
```

then you can use this route in view file to redirect user to that index function.

To convert your last code, we can pass that count value into that view file 
or we can call a function in our model which counts that sub_id,

```
public function getCount($id)
{
    return $this->where('sub_id',$id)->count();
}
```

and we can call from view file as

```
$product->getCount($sub_id)
```

And we can use blade syntax to display value instead of echo like :

```
{!! $count !!} or {!! $product->getCount($sub_id) !!}
```

I hope you got some idea to convert that CI code to laravel. If you are still confused, you can refer official [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1). It will not take too much time to get the things because process are very similar in CI and Laravel.

Comment: category items count in loop

Comment: this code are apply but this code only first item count

Comment: I tasted these codes on my machine and it works. So, please try again or comment your code here.

Comment: sorry not work post your view,controller and model code.

Comment: this cont is in foreach loop

Comment: I think you should give some time to understand some fundamentals of laravel.